# Saving last selected value in Python Script Tool?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.0, python-script-tool

I have created a python script tool with python 2.6 and arcgis 10.0 in which the user parameter reads a field and provide list of field content , below is the list.

[image]

user selects the desired value and run the tool.

now when the user again open the same tool he has to again refine the list to choose desired value.

i want this tool to store previously selected option from the list, so it opens like this: .

[image]

how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 4):

Use Geoprocessing Results list - re-opening a previously run tool will include any parameters selected when that tool was run.

Geoprocessing Menu > Results

[image]

In Results tab open the previously run tool and note the parameters are set as at the last use

[image]

[image]

Comment: i dont know how to add last geoprocessing result in tool, can you please give  more clarification ?

Comment: @AkhilKumar I have added some screenshots

Comment: it will not work as i am going to distribute this tool to other team member, I can not explain everyone to follow this procedure, i want something to implement in my tool validater code.

Comment: It wil take 1 minute to explain this to other team member and hours to implement with great chance of failure

Comment: this solution does not fulfill my desire.

Answer (score 1):

If you have no better ideas, the way that I would try to meet this requirement is by using tool validation to write the value chosen each time to a known file, and then to read that value into the default each time the tool is re-opened.

I have done this to pass values between Python Toolbox tools and Python AddIns, and I *think* it should work to enable a Python Script Tool to *remember* its last used value too.

Comment: yes , it seems to be working in this way.

 if you could implement something like this in python script tool than it would be very helpful for me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Sorry @AkhilKumar , this is not a code writing service.

Comment: you said you have done it before . at least you can tell me how can i write to external file and read it. or can give some reference to read.

Comment: @AkhilKumar It's similar to something I did a year or two ago and which I do not have at my fingertips.  I would have researched how to write/read ASCII files at [so] as a pure Python question.